# Chance that every player got five

Tags: probability

Four players play a game with rolling dice. They play 100 rounds. What's the probability that there was a round where every of them got five?

My solution:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} {100 \choose k} (\frac{1}{6})^{400 \cdot k}(\frac{5}{6})^{400-4k}$$ where $k$ is the number of rounds where every of them got 5. Is it correct? I tried to do this with opposite event but it turned out to not be so trivial.

Comment: Hint: In a single round, what is the probability that every player gets a five?

Comment: Well, it's $(\frac{1}{6})^4$ and now I see I have a typo in my question ;)

Comment: @Nerwena: you wrote "there was a round"... you mean "exactly one round" of "at least one round"?

Comment: @tommik I want at least one round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want at least one round.

Thus  the answer is simply

$$1-\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{6^4}\Bigg)^{100}\approx 7.4\%$$

Comment: But then you count only rounds where none of them got five, what about these where one of them got five, two etc.? Or I'm just complicating it?

Comment: @Nerwena ; these events are included in $(1-1/6^4)^{100}$. Do the same exercise with 2 players and 2 rounds so you can visualize the problem analyzing case by case